# Create a function to spread the amount based on the table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have this problem statement that I do not know how to start.

Given a total amount of 1000 with a duration of 2 month, the spread is 500 and 500, according to the C3 diagram below.

If the durtaion is 3, the spread is 223, 516, and 261, according to D4.
If the duration is 4, the spread is 147, 320, 361 and 173, according to E5.

How should I turn the calculation about in a python function that will return in pandas series?

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption you are given the distribution table shown, you can document the desired distributions in a dict data structure and then use the structure to create the Series as follows:

```
def genSeries(val: float, dur: int):    
    distributions = {1:[1.0], 2:[0.5, 0.5], 3:[0.223, 0.561, 0.261], 
                     4:[0.147, 0.320, 0.361, 0.173],
                    5:[0.108, 0.195, 0.344, 0.222, 0.130]} 
    assert(isinstance(dur, int) and dur in distributions.keys())
    rslt = []
    dist = distributions[dur]
    for frac in dist:
        rslt.append(frac*val)
    return pd.Series(rslt)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works correctly to my case.